# Which event to use for emitting change from inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a React component that has many `<TextInput>` components, which are just simple wrappers around text `<input>` elements. Example:

```
<div>
    <TextInput value={person.FirstName} ... />
    <TextInput value={person.LastName} ... />
</div>
```

I also have some state represented by a person object. For example:

```
{ 
    "FirstName": "Buster", 
    "LastName": "Posey" 
}
```

Each `<TextInput>` component manages it's own internal state, which is the value of the text `<input>` at a given time.

When I click on a Save button, I want to make sure the person object has the most recent values from all of the `<TextInput>` components.

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. **Events** (onKeyDown, onChange, onBlur). An event inside the `<TextInput>` will create an action, it goes through the dispatcher, and the store updates the person object one field at a time.
2. **Refs**. I know this is an anti-pattern, but it really does seem so much simpler. I can iterate over refs when Save is clicked and pull out the state and fire an action.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a simple wrapper around input, give it the same api as input, and don't have it manage internal state it doesn't need to.

```
render(){
    var person = this.state.person;
    return <div>
        <TextInput value={person.FirstName} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} />
        ...
    </div>
},
handleFirstNameChange(name){
    this.setState({person: update(this.state.person, {
        FirstName: {$set: name}
    }});
}
```

<sup><sup>update is React.addons.update, just as an example</sup></sup>

And when save is clicked you send it out in an action.  You can have a store for each piece of temporary data if you really need to, but it's almost always overkill if you don't persist it.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I ended up doing. Use this.setState() to manage the changes and then issue an action into the pipeline when save is clicked. Was struggling because I was trying to stay "pure" with state and avoided using this.setState.